# Удалить символы из строки в PHP

Tags: php

Приходит строка с номером телефона в таком формате

```
+7(777) 133 38 22
```

Как удалить символы `+()` и пробелы из приведенной строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А погуглить?
`$string = str_replace(array('+', '(', ')', ' '), '', $string);`